# Update based on value in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i have table with 3 column. ID,Country and language code. Second table: ID, UserID, ParameterID, ParameterValue. I want to update ParameterValue for choosen ParameterID based on another ParameterValue of choosen ParameterID.
For every UserID in my table i want to update ParameterValue with LangCode from first table.
So in data below if user have matching ParameterValue on ParameterID coresponding to country to value in table1, column Country it will update 44 to 50 for user B71B9338 and for 9A0DC6D8 44 to 58.

First table:

| ID | Country | LangCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B96BXE34 | Germany | 50 |
| 073B4124 | Italy | 58 |

Second table:

| ID | UserID | ParameterID | ParameterValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B96BFE69 | B71B9338 | 57870A4D | Germany |
| E27A929D | B71B9338 | 328E341A | 44 |
| 5DFF9BD1 | 9A0DC6D8 | 57870A4D | Italy |
| DFC9E426 | 9A0DC6D8 | 328E341A | 44 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict the user to be updated with EXISTS

```
update s
set ParameterValue = f.LangCode
from secondTbl s
join firstTbl f on s.ParameterID = '328E341A'
   and exists (
     select 1 
     from secondTbl s2
     where s2.UserID = s.UserID and s2.ParameterID ='57870A4D' and s2.ParameterValue = f.Country)
```